# Unknown provider Error: Angular Unit Testing with Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, karma-jasmine

I am trying to test a controller and a service with karma. Controller Unit test is working fine but its giving me error while testing factory as

```
angular.module('dr.search.services')
.service('registerDoctor', function($uibModal, $rootScope, $timeout, dbService, $q) {
    var registerDoctor= {};

    // functions code

    return registerDoctor;
}
```

Now I am trying to test if this service is defined or not like this

```
describe('Doctor Sign up factory', function() {
  var DocSignUpFactory;

  beforeEach(module('dr.search.services'));
  beforeEach(inject(function(_registerDoctor_) {
    DocSignUpFactory = _registerDoctor_;
  }));

  it('DoctorSignUpFactory should be defined.', inject(function (DocSignUpFactory) {
      expect(DocSignUpFactory).toBeDefined();
  }));
});
```

I have added these files in karma.conf.js like this

```
'app/components/signUpDoctor/signUpDoctor.js',
'app/components/signUpDoctor/signUpDoctor.spec.js',
'app/factories/signUpDoctor/signUpDoctor.js',
'app/factories/signUpDoctor/signUpDoctor.spec.js',
```

When i run karma, it is showing  error in factory unit test as

```
Error:  [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider:  DocSignUpFactoryProvider <- DocSignUpFactory
```

Comment: That's because there's no DocSignUpFactory service. You've already done `DocSignUpFactory = _registerDoctor_` assignment. Don't do `inject(function (DocSignUpFactory) {` injection.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, I have been spending time on it for 4 hours.

Comment: Sure, you're welcome.